# new to XML to Excel mapping (or Access)-want to save and reuse map

Tags: excel, xml, mapping, transform

I am new to XML and Excel mapping, and/or Access and transform files.  I am very proficient with VBA in both Excel and Access.
Monthly XML files are received, 6 of them at this time but this will increase, and I need to extract just a bit of data from each of them.  The same bit of data each month, from the same files. I will store the data in Access, but I don't care if it gets to Excel first, then I can easily get it to Access, or whatever works!
I thought I had it with the mapping and the XML source pane, but it doesn't appear that I can simply "save" a map and reuse it each time.  I have to drop and drag for every file.
I am sure this is a simple problem for you XML wizards!!!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check Powerquery?

Comment: Yes, and that works okay, but for some reason when I select the XLM file, I do not get to see ALL the data, just certain parts of the file.  I am sure it has to do with the XML code itself, again I am not too familiar with it.  I got most of the data but there are one or two more pieces that are text that I'd like to extract.  It pulls into Access just fine, as long as I don't mind sifting through 25 tables when I need only 3!!  And of course the same with just opening in Excel, all the data is there, but so much to get rid of to get the pertinent parts each time.

Comment: You have to do that only once (get the pertinent parts) - the "rules" are stored within the query.

Comment: Okay, I see where I am messing up.  Going to fast and not really looking at things clearly.

Comment: But, I have this one section, that if I edit the query, all the data I want is shown there (I had to expand a "table" section to see all I wanted), but it stops at column 4, I have 9 more columns that I can see in the query editor but not the results when you close and load.

Comment: At this point I think I may just dump it all into Access, write code to pull what I want out, and delete all the new tables. There is a whole section "-<rsm:ReportedHierarchicalStructure>", that doesn't show up as an option to even choose in PQ.

Comment: It's very hard to give you an advise without knowing the XML file ...